# type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>?' of 'value'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am     trying to build a multi chip selection field using the below code in dart.

test_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_select_flutter/multi_select_flutter.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _gamePreferences = [
      GamePreference(id: 0, name: "Tennis"),
      GamePreference(id: 1, name: "Football")
    ].map((pref) => MultiSelectItem<GamePreference>(pref, pref.name)).toList();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Profile"),
      ),
      body: MultiSelectChipField(onTap: (value) {}, items: _gamePreferences),
    );
  }
}

class GamePreference {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  GamePreference({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

Here is the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/test_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      home: Container(child: TestWidget()),
    );
  }
}
```

But, when i select any object in the multi select i get the below error

> ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following _TypeError
> was thrown while handling a gesture: type 'List<GamePreference?>' is
> not a subtype of type 'List?' of 'value'
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
> #0      FormFieldState.didChange (package:flutter/src/widgets/form.dart)
> package:flutter/…/widgets/form.dart:1
> #1      __MultiSelectChipFieldViewState._buildItem. package:multi_select_flutter/chip_field/multi_select_chip_field.dart:515
> #2      _RawChipState._handleTap package:flutter/…/material/chip.dart:1772
> #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:989
> #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182 ... Handler: "onTap"
> Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#8cfb5
> debugOwner: GestureDetector
> state: possible
> won arena
> finalPosition: Offset(32.0, 148.0)
> finalLocalPosition: Offset(24.0, 17.0)
> button: 1
> sent tap down ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: Do you know what that error means? What the compiler complains about? Can you post an [mcve] please?

Comment: Added the minimal reproducible example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the

final _gamePreferences = [
GamePreference(id: 0, name: "Tennis"),
GamePreference(id: 1, name: "Football")
].map((pref) => MultiSelectItem(pref, pref.name)).toList();

to

final _gamePreferences = [
GamePreference(id: 0, name: "Tennis"),
GamePreference(id: 1, name: "Football")
].map((pref) => **MultiSelectItem<GamePreference?>**(pref, pref.name)).toList();

this will solve the error

the list you passed in MultiSelectChipField has the  MultiSelectItem data type while MultiSelectChipField required MultiSelectItem<T?>.

'List<Object?>' = Means object can be null
'List?' = Means the whole list can be null

So there is a difference between these two

when you assign the List<String?> to List?  then it will throw this error.

So, Make sure the value you are assigned to the list is having the same data type.

Answer (score 1):

`List<String?>` is: "a definitely non-null list, that might contain `String`s or `null`s"

`List<String>?` is: "`null`, or a `List` containing non-null `String`s"

```dart
// these are all fine
List<String?> list1 = ['hello', null, 'world'];
List<String>? list2 = ['hello', 'world'];
List<String>? list3 = null;

// these are compile errors
List<String?> list4 = null;  // List is not nullable
List<String>? list5 = ['hello', null, 'world'];  // element type is not nullable
```

Without more information on your specific issue, it's hard to give a more detailed answer, but this is the difference between `List<T?>` and `List<T>?` in general.

Comment: Added the code snipper which is runnable (except the pubspec entry which is multi_select_flutter: ^4.0.0). Hope that helps with additional information.